# Error After Adding Redux Provider: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')" - i didnt use usememo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm facing an issue after integrating Redux and the `<Provider>` component into my React application. Despite the application running smoothly before this addition, I now encounter a "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')" error. Moreover, it appears that the Redux store is not being created successfully.
i did not use useMemo hook in my code!

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ApplyChange from './redux/rootReducer';

const store = createStore(ApplyChange);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

versions:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.2",
"redux" : "^4.2.1"


rootReducer.js 

    const initialValue = {
    perms: [],
  };
  
  const ApplyChange = (state = initialValue, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SETPERMS':
        return { ...state, perms : action.payload };
    
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default ApplyChange;

  

error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at Object.useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at Provider (Provider.js:14:1)...
The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:

    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41257:3)
```

Comment: May be version conflict issue. Try to install latest version of react-redux and redux. What version of redux you are using?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: `useMemo` is a React hook, e.g. `React.useMemo`, so it seems the error is telling you that `React` is null for some reason. Have you ensured all project dependencies are correctly installed? There's not really enough code here to provide enough context for what might be causing the issue. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that includes all the redux code you are working with? Can you also include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace so we can see where the code is falling over?

Answer (score -1):

The function of useMemo is a hook which is belong React itself so you are using in somewhere(Maybe App.js). That could be causing the error. Just implement it to your component. If you share other codes with us then we can help you about problem.

Comment: i did not use useMemo hook in my code, i think it triggered by<provider>, here is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at Object.useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at Provider (Provider.js:14:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)...
    The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:

    at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:80486:3)

Comment: Then only possibility is like your packages and their compatibilities as @CodeThing said because i used same code with my project i did not get any error. I am sharing packages.

`"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.2",
"redux": "^4.2.1"`

Delete your **node_modules ** directory and **package_lock.json** file and `npm install` again.

Comment: This should be a comment since it doesn't really provide an answer.

Comment: Actually my reputation is so low so i can not comment. @janaSM needs help. I will try to help. Thanks for your warning.